# Help with wiring to change three way switches to two single pole

Tags: electrical

Below are diagrams of the crazy wiring I have for three way switches operating two light fixtures.  I would like to be able to change them from three way switches to two single pole switches each operating the nearest light fixture.  Does the info in the diagrams help me at all to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for advice and guidance.[image: wiring diagram #1]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's hard to see just what the diagrams are; you might get better answers if you redrew them.

Comment: Better yet, can you get us good photos of the innards of the boxes?  (Not just the switch boxes, but the light fixture boxes too)